# Calling React Routes Through Proxy Node js server not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, http-proxy

This is my proxy code which is running on port 5000
So if i use proxy.web(req, res, { target: "http://localhost:3000" }); it is redirecting me to the react app but if i call the login component using proxy.web(req, res, { target: "http://localhost:3000/login" }); , its not redirecting me to the Login Component

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const userCookie = req.cookies.user;
  const url = req.originalUrl;
  var pattern = /\/api\//;
  if (userCookie ) { //if cookie is present
    if (pattern.test(url)) {  
      next();
      console.log("Contains API")
    } else {  //if url doesnt contains /api
      proxy.web(req, res, { target: "http://localhost:3000" });
      console.log("/login:3000");
    }
  }else if(url== '/api/login'){ 
    console.log("login");
    next();
  } 
  else {  // if cookie not set
    if (pattern.test(url)) { //if url contains /api
      res.status(401).send("plz login in");
      console.log("login Required");
    } else { 
      console.log("http://localhost:3000/login");
      proxy.web(req, res, { target: "http://localhost:3000/login" });
    }
  }
});
```

And this is my Router code in react app which is running on port 3000

```
<BrowserRouter>
    {/* <App/> */}
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/' element={<App/>}/>
      <Route path='/login' element={<Login/>}/>
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

I tried using http-proxy package

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to handle this would be from the react app itself whenever there is a 401 error with the help of Axios and global interceptor and redirect it to the login page for that specific error

Or you do something like this

```
<Route
            exact
            path="/"
            render={() => {
                return (
                  this.state.hasUserCookies ?
                  <Redirect to="/home" /> :
                  <Redirect to="/login" /> 
                )
            }}
          />
```

If you are trying to start the react app itself from the node server then what you are trying to achieve might be hard as the router might not have been mounted/rendered by then miss out on the originally requested route and just load up default or home route.

Comment: Actually my requirement is, everything what happens on react app, has to go through proxy server, hence I do all the checks in proxy server